# How can I filter blog name?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters, hooks

I want to filter the blog's name for Google's user agents.

I have tried `the_title`, `the_content`, `comment_text`, `single_post_title`, `wp_title`, `category_description`, `bloginfo` hooks, but none of them worked!

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

The value is from `get_option('blogname')`, so you can filter `pre_option_blogname`:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_blogname', 'wpse_78345_blogname' );

function wpse_78345_blogname()
{
    return 'Haha!';
}
```

Do not filter `option_blogname`. This is wrong: you are wasting time with that, because WordPress will parse the option cache for the stored result, and then you don’t even use it.

Comment: as I know `pre` if for detabase writes. I just want to edit blogname for google user agents!

Comment: I forgot to say that I want to filter it for google's user agents!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee Then go and edit your question with this info, please (also the title).

Comment: I don't think the title need to be changed. But I edited the question

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee No, `pre_option_` happens very early in `get_option`. How to handle [cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking) based on User-Agent headers is off topic here.

Answer (score 3):

You said that you have tried using the `bloginfo` filter, but this code works fine:

```
function wpse_78345_alter_blog_name( $output, $show ) {
    if ( $show != 'name' ) return $output;
    return 'New blog title';
}

add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'wpse_78345_alter_blog_name', 10, 2 );
```

This filter will only fire on the front-end, not the dashboard.